# pivot_longer with separate

Tags: r, tidyr

Suppose I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ids=c('1,2','3,4'), vals=c('a', 'b'))
```

and I want to end up with this one:

```
data.frame(ids=c('1', '2', '3', '4'), vals=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'))
```

In words: one separate row for each value in the comma-separated lists in ids, with the associated vals duplicated.

I'd like to use the tidyverse.  I'm pretty sure I should use pivot_longer, maybe with names_sep, but after reading and fiddling it's not obvious to me.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` instead of `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(ids)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  ids   vals 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 1     a    
#2 2     a    
#3 3     b    
#4 4     b
```